# How to add external .js script to my index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my public/index.html I need to load external .js file which will be used later during deployment.
Unfornately that file doesnt load when i npm start, nor when published in build. I dont get any error either. The file config.js is in public directory as well.

Added this to my index.html in  tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" scr="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>`

config.js looks like this:

```
alert(5);
var test=5;
```

I get no error in console, but it doesnt resolve at all. Nothing happens.
(i've tried playing with paths, googling around for hours but no luck. I guess there must be some security setting in react or something that prevents me from loading that script?)

ps: i am tring this which is not working for same reason for me: https://www.cotyhamilton.com/build-once-deploy-anywhere-for-react-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not my longest answer. You need to fix the typo, the correct attribute is `src` not `scr` on your `script` tag. If you change it, it will work fine:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/config.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Nagyon szépen köszönjük. Console should notice typos i guess :)